# perl split and combine dictionary phrase string with / in it (for better access of phrase entries)

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have two strings: `be/feel like a new A/B` and `feel like a new/old A/B`. The first one needs to be splitted into four strings as follows:
`be like a new A`, `be like a new B`, `feel like a new A`, `feel like a new B` and the second one needs to be splitted into four also:
`feel like a new A`, `feel like a new B`, `feel like a old A`, `feel like a old B`.

In perl, can we do such special splitting?
Thanks in advance.

Update:I have tried the following, but due to the uncertain potential order of `$with_slash` and `$without_slash` within `$a`, so far I couldn't think of a way to do it.

```
my $a = "be/feel like a new A/B/C";
my $with_slash = qr!\S+/\S+!;
my $without_slash = qr![^\n/]!;
my @list = $a =~ m!((($with_slash)|($without_slash))+)!g;
```

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
my $pat = "be/feel like a new A/B";

my $glob = "";
my @parts = split(qr{( \w++ (?: / \w++ )++ )}x, $pat, -1);
for my $i (0..$#parts) {
   if ($i % 2 == 0) {
      $glob .= quotemeta($parts[$i]);
   } else {
      $glob .= "{".( $parts[$i] =~ s{/}{,}rg )."}";
   }
}

my @list = glob($glob);
```

or

```perl
my $pat = "be/feel like a new A/B";

my $glob = "";
for ($pat) {
   m{\G \W++ }xgc
      and do { $glob .= quotemeta($&); redo; };
   m{\G \w++ (?: / \w++ )++ }xgc
      and do { $glob .= "{".( $& =~ s{/}{,}rg )."}"; redo; };
   m{\G \w++ }xgc
      and do { $glob .= $&; redo; };
   m{\G \z }xgc
      or die("Bad data\n");
}

my @list = glob($glob);
```

These produce `{be,feel}\ like\ a\ new\ {A,B}` from `be/feel like a new A/B`, which `glob` can extend into the desired list.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do it. One way would be to split the string on whitespace into tokens. Tokens are joined back into strings, stored in the array of outputs (each element is a growing string). Every time we encounter a token with one or more forward slashes, we split on slash into variants, and add each variant into the array of outputs, using 2 nested `map` operations (which act like two loops here).

```
echo "be/feel like a new A/B\nfeel like a new/old A/B" | \
    perl -e '
use warnings;
use strict;
while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    my @tokens = split / /, $_;
    # Array with 1 element = empty string, to enable joining words:
    my @outputs = ( q{} ); 
    foreach my $token ( @tokens ) {
        my @variants = split m{/}, $token; 
        @outputs = map { my $old_str = $_; map { "$old_str $_" } @variants } @outputs
    }
    # Remove leading blanks that resulted from the first empty string:
    @outputs = map { my $str = $_; $str =~ s/^\s+//; $str } @outputs;
    print "outputs for: $_:\n";
    print "$_\n" for @outputs;
}
'
```

This prints:

```
outputs for: be/feel like a new A/B:
be like a new A
be like a new B
feel like a new A
feel like a new B
outputs for: feel like a new/old A/B:
feel like a new A
feel like a new B
feel like a old A
feel like a old B
```

---

This can handle strings of any length, with any number of tokens, of which any number of them is has any number of slashes (provided the arrays fit in RAM). The strings are processed one per line.